# Can't retreive logged user from ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in Spring Aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop, spring-webflux

I want to write simple aspect for enabling Hibernate filtering on some services. I need it for implementing some "visibility rules".
But i don't know how to do it with WebFlux. `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` returns nothing, when i call it in `@Around` aspect. I have debugged code and found that authentication starts before Aspect execution and ending after Aspect execution finished. Anybody know solution to this problem ? How can i retreive logged in user from aspect when using webflux ?
My aspect:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.shs.crm.dao.service.user.*.*(..))")
public void dataAccessOperation() {
    logger.info("dataAccessOperation performed");
}
@Around("com.shs.aspect.DataSecurityAspect.dataAccessOperation()")
public Object doAccessCheck(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint)
        throws Throwable {
    Object returnObject;
    if (proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget() instanceof CrmUserService) {
        try {
           Long userId = customSecurityService.getCurrentUserId().toFuture().get();//here i have IllegalStateException
        } catch (Exception noContext) {
            logger.debug(
                    "No Security Context associated with current thread - assuming least access");
        }
        // Here i will enable filter
        returnObject = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } else {
        // here i will disable filter
        returnObject = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
    return returnObject;
}
```

Service for retreiving current user:

```
    @Service
public class CustomSecurityService {
    public Mono<Long> getCurrentUserId() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("ReactiveSecurityContext is empty")))
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .map(Authentication::getName)
                .map(Long::parseLong);
    }
}
```

Security:

```
@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
        String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> {
                return new SecurityContextImpl(authentication);
            });
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

}

@Component
public class AuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private CrmUserService userService;

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        Long userId;
        try {
            userId = jwtUtil.getUserIdFromToken(authToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            userId = null;
        }
        if (userId != null && jwtUtil.validateToken(authToken)) {

            Map<String, Claim> claims = jwtUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(authToken);
            Set<Long> permissions = userService.getUserPermissionsIds(userId);
            //List<Long> permissions = claims.get("permissions").asList(Long.class);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userId,
                null,
                    permissions.stream().map( permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
            return Mono.just(auth);
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

    List<String> getPermissionsNamesByIds(List<Long> ids){
        return ids.stream().map(id -> {
            CrmPermission.AvailablePermissions permission = (CrmPermission.AvailablePermissions)CrmPermission.AvailablePermissions.fromValue(id.intValue());
            return permission.getCode();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

I can get current user only from controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Mono<CrmUserDto> getAccount(Principal principal) {
        return customSecurityService.getCurrentUserId().flatMap(userId -> {
            CrmUser currentUser = userRepository.findOneByIdWithRoles(userId);
            CrmUserDto userDTO = modelMapperService.map(currentUser, CrmUserDto.class);
            return Mono.just(userDTO);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole code source for the aspect, the controller and the injection part.

Comment: are you trying this on test or in real execution?

Comment: I tried this on real execution

Comment: If is real execution, spring should call ReactorContextWebFilter which is in charge of set auth on ReactiveSecurityContextHolder after call your AuthenticationManager, if is not there should be something wrong with you config.

Comment: I'm sorry for disinformation, i tried to get user id in my CrmUserService and it returned same error, only place where i can retreive user is controller (using Principal agument).

Comment: thanks, i will check my authentication logic

Comment: as i think, you dont need this aspect, you are trying to do something like this post https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions so user will automatically inject to query use

Comment: cool, i didn't know about this feature. But i have to use aspect, because i have service which uses criteria api and i hope it protect me from forgetting to add criteria in one of the methods

Comment: I can get current user only in my controller, because i use flatMap and don't block the thread. As i understand i couldn't use ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in my Aspect because it returns Mono and i can't get value of it in Aspect, because blocking operations is not permitted.

Comment: Well, first you have to decide if your app will be reactive or blocking

Comment: after a little search i found this like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137150/how-to-get-the-object-returned-from-joinpoint-proceed-with-spring-aop-and-webf

Comment: For additional context, you can see that Spring Security does something similar with its own interceptors for the `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.java#L84 It's a different AOP library, but the same concept.

Comment: I saw these links, but no answer there(. The main problem is that Mono is populating only if it returned at Controller level. I can't spend more time on this task, so i will make it without aspect. Thanks for your attention guys

Comment: it will be easier if your share your source on public repo, because right now is like going blind.